# rewrite condition for matching querystring

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to check if any querystring comes with ? and = symbols

```
/user/person/1  is should be valid
/user/person/date/21 is should be valid

/user/?page=Reg  if something comes like this I just want to throw a 404
```

Now i want to do these change in htaccess file,

Can anyone help me to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?.*=.*
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: thank you. But I have to block url like "/user/da?page=Reg" this too

Comment: @Ha329is `/user/da?page=Reg` will result in a 404 with that rule

Comment: ya yes yes. sorry I hv't noticed.